# MVT - applying it to two curves that intersect

Tags: calculus

Assume $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. $C1$ is the curve defined by $p(x)$ and $C2$ by $y=e^x$. Show that there are at most n distinct points of intersection between the two curves.

Ok, so I think what you should do here is note $p(x) = e^x$. And the derivative of $p(x)$ is simply a constant since it is of degree n(please correct me where I'm wrong), as well with $e^x$ still being $e^x$. How can I show that there are at most n distinct roots of intersections between the two curves here noting this information?

Comment: I think this is more related to use a logarithm scale in the $x$ axis. Then $p(x)$ have at most $n$ real zeros.

Comment: "The derivative of $p(x)$  is simply a constant since it is of degree $n$" ??

Comment: The nth derivative of $p(x)$ is a constant since it is a polynomial of  degree n.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=e^x-p(x)$. If there would be infinitely many roots of $f$ then $f'$ would also have infinitely many roots (using MVT). If $f'$ has infinitely many roots, again using MVT, $f''$ has infinitely many roots. Continuing in this fashion, for all $m$, $f^{(m)}$ should have infinitely many roots. However, $f^{(n+1)}$ is just $e^x$ which has no roots.

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding your last point. Are you saying $e^x$ will never equal 0? Or that when you've essentially differentiated n+1 times $p(x)$ will equal to $0$ and all we will have left is $e^x$?(which will never be equal to $p(x)$ as at this point it is equal to 0, a number $e^x$ will never reach?

Comment: If my above comment is right then you should put that as an answer imo.